# How to achieve accurate rotation of fingers at the point they meet the palm?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have problems with fingers in general but this is the hardest part for me.

It looks ok at this point:

[image]

But if I rotate at the base of the finger, problems start:

[image]

This is because the rotation point should be around the middle of the knuckles, at least that's what I think:

[image]

I changed the bones to rotate from that point, but I really can't achieve a good look. Any tips? I have no idea how to make any significant improvement. That whole knuckle area that connects to the fingers rotates too, but I'm not sure how I can make it rotate and deform correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Your fingers have segments of wrong lengths. Model the hand closer to the anatomy - the segments shouldn't be about the same lengths but shorter the further from the palm. This alone should mitigate your problem a lot. Tissue bulging and colliding can be done with shapekeys.

Comment: Can you actually bend your real fingers like the second image? I can't. If I curl my fingers like the first pic, then my knuckles push outward to allow the curl.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to insert in your rig a driven shape key, to ensure that you get the exact deformed mesh you desire. The shape key can be triggered only when a certain amount of rotation is reached.